# gwt-maven-plugin soyc flags

Tags: gwt, compiler-flags, gwt-compiler

I've been having some problems with GWT and SOYC. 
Using the maven pluging for gwt: gwt-maven-plugin, how can I pass extra flags to the GWT compiler. I'm trying to set the XsoycDetailed flag, so that I can get a detailed SOYC report. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html

soycDetailed:

add -XsoycDetailed parameter to the compiler command line
Can be set from command line using '-Dgwt.compiler.soycDetailed=true'.

example: mvn -Dgwt.compiler.soycDetailed=true install